# Find number in given range without if statement in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 3 inputs Number min and max

- if number is in range between min and max the function should return number
- if number is less than min the function should return min
- if number is greater than max the function should return max

  ```
  3,4,5 -> 4
  3,1,7 -> 3
  9,1,7 -> 7
  ```

I have tried doing it but cannot do it without if statement
Hint : Need to use Math function

```
function minCalulator(number,min,max){
    if(Math.min(number,min) == number){
        return min;
    }
    if(Math.min(number,max) === max){
            return max;
    }
    return number;
}
```

How to implement this without if or any conditional statements?

Comment: This is a simple problem and I strongly suggest you'll try to find an answer on your own.

Comment: hint: you already have the `Math.min` and `Math.max` functions that select one of two given values. Is there a way to break your "three numbers" problem into two "two numbers" problems?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried more and found out

Math.min(Math.max(number,min),max);

Answer (score 1):

here you are first checking for the max of `number` and `max`, then checking for the minimum of the `min` and the other comparison.

```js
const minCalculator = (number, min, max) => Math.max(min, Math.min(number, max))

const test1 = minCalculator(3,4,5)
const test2 = minCalculator(3,1,7)
const test3 = minCalculator(9,1,7)

console.log(test1, test1 === 4)
console.log(test2, test2 === 3)
console.log(test3, test3 === 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Math.min()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) return the smallest in an array of numbers.

```
Math.min(3,4,5) will output 3
Math.max(3,4,5) will output 5
```

You could do:

```
var x = Math.min(number,maxNumber) //if the number is bigger than the maximum, x will keep the maximum, if the number is smaller than the max, x will keep number.
```

then

```
var x = Math.max(x,minNumber) //same principal
```

x will finally hold a number that is in the range you need.

Here's a fiddle with what you're looking for:
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akncmhbt/)

Answer (score 0):

If only 3 numbers will be used, you can try to send values to function as an array, find min max and get them out, after this return array like that.

```
function myFunction(_numbers) 
{
   var indexMax = _numbers.indexOf(Math.max(_numbers));
   _numbers.splice(indexMax, 1);
   var indexMin = _numbers.indexOf(Math.min(_numbers));
   _numbers.splice(indexMin, 1);
   return _numbers;
}
```

Important!! This logic only works if you have 3 numbers in array like your examples.